# I am unable to select another country from input type drop down in react js

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I want to select another country in input type react js drop down, but I am not able to select the country.

I want further code after the below mentioned code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/main/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]")).click();

Thread.sleep(2000);
```

[image: Inspect element is mentioned in an image.]

Comment: Please, explain a bit more and put a bit more code

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask]. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers. What exactly happens? An error? A silent failure? Can you provide the associated HTML?